# Command-line tool to add a cover picture to mp3 / m4a files (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, command-line, audio, mp3, media

I'm using Windows 10 (which complicates things).

So I have a bunch of music files and associated cover picture in the form of "x.m4a" and "x.jpg". I would like to associate them.

A command-line tool would be ideal since it could be easily run in a batch. Basically, I would like to use this:

```
@for /R %%F in (*.m4a) do (
    <utility> "%%~F" +cover "%%~npF.jpg"
)
```

Neither Foobar2000 nor Mp3tag provide a CLI, so I tried with ffmpeg directly but it automatically converts the picture in png which I don't want.

I tried using id3 mass tagger with

```
id3 -2 -wAPIC "test.jpg" "test.mp3"
```

But it returned with "writing `APIC' frames is not supported".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [tageditor](https://github.com/Martchus/tageditor) which provides a CLI:

```
@for /R %%F in (*.mp3,*.m4a) do (
    if exist "%%~npF.jpg" (
        tageditor set cover="%%~npF.jpg" -f "%%F"
    )
)
```

I am not sure if [mid3v2](https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/man/mid3v2.html) from the Mutagen suite would have worked, because at some point I corrupted my test files (trying so many applications) so I might have unfairly ruled out Mutagen.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried eyed3?

You can install it doing:

```
sudo apt-get install eyed3
```

And then you can try:

```
eyeD3 --add-image "<your picture>.jpg:FRONT_COVER" test.mp3
```

As mentioned in the specs, keep in mind:

```
  --add-image IMG_PATH:TYPE[:DESCRIPTION]
                        Add or replace an image. There may be more than one image in a tag, as long as the DESCRIPTION values are unique. The default
                        DESCRIPTION is ''. If PATH begins with 'http[s]://' then it is interpreted as a URL instead of a file containing image data. The
                        TYPE must be one of the following: OTHER, ICON, OTHER_ICON, FRONT_COVER, BACK_COVER, LEAFLET, MEDIA, LEAD_ARTIST, ARTIST, CONDUCTOR,
                        BAND, COMPOSER, LYRICIST, RECORDING_LOCATION, DURING_RECORDING, DURING_PERFORMANCE, VIDEO, BRIGHT_COLORED_FISH, ILLUSTRATION,
                        BAND_LOGO, PUBLISHER_LOGO.
```

More info about the specs [here](https://eyed3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/classic_plugin.html).

Comment: I'm on Windows 10, which cuts a lot of nice and easy options. I'll edit my post to clarify.

Comment: Ah, indeed, yes, it does cut a lot of nice options. I know lame isn't normally used for that but for multiple files, it seems like a good option if you can't find anything else, have you thought about using lame in the cmd prompt? Otherwise, I know it's possible using Windows Media Player, we can still find it even if it's not automatically included in Windows 10, but I know it's super easy to add cover art using it. For multiple files, it may be a bit tedious thought...

Comment: Lame doesn't support AAC files which constitute the majority of tracks I want to tag. In addition, it seems to reencode the files (?) even with only the --ti option.

Comment: Yes, Lame wasn't originally made for that but it can still be done using it. I found a Windows-only freeware which seems nice, maybe you can try it out: [mp3tag](https://www.mp3tag.de/en/)  . It supports many formats, including AAC.

Comment: Thank you but mp3tag, as well as foobar2000, cannot be used in command-line. I really don't want to tag my 200+ files by hand :(

Comment: Have you tried [Mutagen](https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/man/index.html) ? It has a CLI.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try kid3-cli, for instance the following command copy all tags including the cover image from an mp3 to an m4a (aac):

```
kid3-cli -c 'select in.mp3' -c copy -c 'select out.m4a' -c paste -c save
```